# How to get a list of lines deleted as part of a TFS Changeset?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

Problem: I had a programmer make deletes in Visual Studio 2013 on 8000+ asp pages over 100+ changesets and some of the lines that got deleted were not supposed to be deleted. I cannot rollback the changesets as too much work would be lost. I am trying to determine if I can get into a single file the contents of the lines that were deleted in a changeset and which file they were from so I can search the content to determine which files need to be corrected.  I understand a comparison of each file in the changeset to the prior version would give me that information but I do not have the time to do a prior comparison for 8000+ individual pages.  I need a way to get the deleted content into a format I can search at one time.  Is this possible in SQL or TFS?

Environment info:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
- Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 (30324.00)
- SQL Server 2012 SP1

Additional notes:

I have researched Team Foundation Power Tools and found that TFPT.exe does not give me what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several of the output formats of [`tf diff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fd7dc73(v=vs.100).aspx) (such as `/format:unified`) will display all of the differences in the changeset at once. You can redirect the output of that command to a file and then filter it down or search for the deletions.